# Dynamic treshold line in a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, threshold

I have a stacked bar char where I want to add a dynamic threshold line. The threshold is calculated via a simple formular (90% of each specific value)

Graphic attached. The green line is what I am looking for. Looking forward for any idea how to approach this problem.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your attempts so far.

Comment: threshold = [0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8]
    ax.plot([0, 7], [threshold, threshold], "k--") - adds 8 lines over the chart

Comment: please post how your data is structured, ie do you plot from numpy arrays, or a pandas dataframe, ...? So that answers can start from this common base.

Comment: just for sake of completeness please clarify if threshold is at 80% (from legend) or 90% (from question text) - in the end it doesn't matter as a parameter in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

The idea was to have a continuous segment of `X`s projected with a constant `y` value with a 0.5 excess before and after:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

groups = 9

X = list(range(1, groups))
y = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]

threshold_interval_x = np.arange(min(X) - 0.5, max(X) + 0.5, 0.01).tolist()

threshold_y = []
for y_elt in y:
    for i in range(0, int(len(threshold_interval_x) / (groups - 1))):
        threshold_y.append(y_elt * 0.9)

plt.bar(X, y, width=0.4, align='center', color='yellow')

plt.plot(threshold_interval_x, threshold_y, color='green')

labels_X = ['PD', 'PZV', 'PP', 'FW', 'BA', 'IA', 'EA', 'NA']
plt.xticks(X, labels_X, rotation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

And here's the output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You could use matplotlibs `step`-function for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

supposed your data is structured like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'In': [1, 1, 1, 2 , 0, 2, 0, 0], 'Out': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]}, index=['PD', 'PZV', 'PP', 'FW', 'BA', 'IA', 'EA', 'NA'])

     In  Out
PD    1    0
PZV   1    0
PP    1    1
FW    2    0
BA    0    1
IA    2    0
EA    0    1
NA    0    1
```

Then plotting the bars would be

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0, color=['gold', 'beige'])
```

and plotting the threshold line at 90% of the sum would be

```
plt.step(df.index, df.sum(1) * .9, 'firebrick', where='mid', label = 'Ziel: 90%')
```

add legend:

```
plt.legend()
```

leads to:

[image]

Comment: Hi, very weird. I 100% copy & pasted your code, and my result is: https://preview.ibb.co/k75UWd/330_EEA37_C0_F7_402_B_A465_AEC1_B5_A07_B1_E.png

Comment: I assume with 100% you mean including definition of df, not applying my plotting to your dataset. Could you check the output of df and df.sum(1)? Do they have the same index columns? and if so, is python, pandas and matplotlib up to date?